# How can I build a query in django using an iterator?

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I build a complex query in django using an iterator? Actually, I feel this could be more of "basic python" than django, but it's got me stumped.

Essentially, I want to take a list object and generate the equivalent of this:

```
SELECT FROM examples WHERE mystuff LIKE 'EX1' OR mystuff LIKE 'EX2';
```

Here's some sample code from my attempts.

```
from example.models import Examples
from django.db.models import Q

includes = ['EX1', 'EX2']

conditions = []
# I can do something like this, which does build a list of objects
for ex in excludes:
    conditions.append(~Q(fullblock_icontains='%s' % ex))

# print conditions
# [<django.db.models.query_utils.Q object at 0x03557AB0>, 
# <django.db.models.query_utils.Q object at 0x03557AD0>]

# then I need to do something like this, but obviously this won't work.
blocks = Examples.objects.filter('|'.split(conditions))
```

Also, I will want to do the same thing, but negatively (~Q). I figure once we work out the LIKE, the NOT LIKE will become apparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import operator
qobjects = [ ~Q(...), Q(...), Q(...) ]
f = reduce(operator.or_, qobjects)
Examples.objects.filter(*f)
```

Comment: Excellent. This did exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check [the doc for generating OR clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

To chain `Q`s together, try `operator.or_`

```
import operator
blocks = Examples.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, conditions))
# which works as
blocks = Examples.objects.filter(conditions[0]|conditions[1]|...)
```